# Using a UITable to link to different pages in a notebook app (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, image, ipad, uitableview

I'm making a note taking app for the iPad, and it lets the user draw lines, and right now, it can save the pages of the notebook by saving each page as a PNG in the documents directory. Here's the code I have to save the images:

```
- (IBAction)saveImage:(id)sender {

UIImage *saveImage = drawImage.image;

if (saveImage != nil)
  {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                      [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@-%d.png", @"image", numberOfPages] ];
    NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(saveImage);
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
  }

}
```

Just as a side note, `numberOfPages` is an int that is set to add 1 each time a "new page" button is pressed, this way, each image is named "image1", "image2", etc.

So my question is: How would I set up a `UITable` so the user can see a list of all the pages they've made.

Thanks so much for your time,

Karl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you make a new page, add a string with the image's name to an array. Then, iterate through the array to populate a UITableView. When the user selects a cell, open the file with that name.

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize keys, names;
AppDelegate *appD;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    appD = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
    names = appD.data;
    NSArray *array = [[names allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    keys = array;
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [keys count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *nameSection = [names objectForKey:key];
    return [nameSection count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSUInteger section = indexPath.section;
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;

    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *nameSection = [appD.data objectForKey:key];

    static NSString *SectionsTableIdentifier = @"SectionsTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.text = [nameSection objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    key = [key substringFromIndex:2];
    return key;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger section = indexPath.section;
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;

    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *nameSection = [appD.data objectForKey:key];

    appD.theInfo.primary = [nameSection objectAtIndex:row];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"secondarySegue" sender:self];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

This is for a table in a navigation controller that populates itself from a .plist and moves to another table when a cell is clicked. The tableview is connected to the view controller with delegate and datasource outlets.

Comment: Yes, I know, but how would I do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a tableview? What do you know how to do and what do you not know how to do?

Comment: I know how to make a tableview, I just don't know how to add things to it. I have this so far:     pagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
        [pagesArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@-%d.png", @"image", numberOfPages]];       But, it doesn't show up in the table. I think I would have to put something in viewDidLoad so that the table would bring up the items inside, but I don't know if that would work or how to implement that.

Comment: Set your controller as the tableview datasource and delegate, then just implement cellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection. At that point, all you have to do is call reloadData on the tableview every time you add something to the array.